# Sublime Text 3 HTML files comments are not angle brackets but curly brackets

Tags: html, sublimetext3, comments

When toggle comments with `ctrl+/` on HTML or VueComponent files syntax with Sublime Text 3 the comments that appear are `{{-- Comment text --}}` instead of the correct ones `<!-- Comment text -->`.

How to make ST to add correct comments?

Edit as @MattDMo advised in comments below: add the list of installed packages.

```json
        "A File Icon",
        "All Autocomplete",
        "AutoFileName",
        "Babel",
        "BracketHighlighter",
        "Chai Completions",
        "Color Highlighter",
        "Colorcoder",
        "CSS Extended Completions",
        "DocBlockr",
        "Dockerfile Syntax Highlighting",
        "DotENV",
        "Edge Syntax Highliter",
        "Emmet",
        "HTML-CSS-JS Prettify",
        "JavaScript & NodeJS Snippets",
        "JavaScript Completions",
        "JavaScript Snippets",
        "JavaScriptNext - ES6 Syntax",
        "JSON Reindent",
        "LanguageTool",
        "Laravel Blade Highlighter",
        "LESS",
        "MarkdownEditing",
        "MarkdownPreview",
        "nginx",
        "Nunjucks Syntax",
        "Package Control",
        "PHP Companion",
        "PHP Completions Kit",
        "PHP-Twig",
        "phpfmt",
        "PHPGrammar",
        "PhpNamespace",
        "PHPUnit Completions",
        "Select Quoted",
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "SublimeCodeIntel",
        "SublimeLinter",
        "SublimeLinter-annotations",
        "SublimeLinter-tslint",
        "TypeScript",
        "TypeScript Syntax",
        "TypescriptCompletion",
        "Vue Syntax Highlight",
        "Vuejs Complete Package",
        "zenburn"
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the regular built-in HTML syntax? Try clicking **`View → Syntax → HTML`** and see if that changes the behavior. I know the Djaneiro package has a Django-HTML syntax that uses double curly braces as comment delimiters.

Comment: @MattDMo, Hey. Thanks for the hint. Yes, I am sure I use HTML syntax. I had done as you described with no effect. I know some syntax packages for HTML template engines comment diffrerently, e.g. Twig, Blade, Edge etc, But this is not the case here.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and post which packages you have installed? You can find the list in **`Preferences → Package Settings → Package Control → Settings`**.

Comment: @MattDMo thanks, added the installed packages list.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way to tell which package is highjacking your HTML commenting is to put (nearly) all of them in your `"ignored_packages"` setting, verify that the desired behavior has returned, then start removing packages from `"ignored_packages"` and see which one triggers the undesired behavior.

You can find (or create) `"ignored_packages"` in `Preferences.sublime-settings` in your `Packages/User` folder. The `Packages` directory is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`

You can make the process go a little faster by removing packages from `"ignored_packages"` three or five at a time, then going down to one by one when the bad behavior comes back. Also, you don't need to ignore clearly innocent packages like Package Control, Zenburn, A File Icon, etc. Good luck!

Comment: true. Thank you for the hints.